# Where does Apache Airflow store task attributes (e.g. for BigQueryOperator)?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

From the Airflow Web UI, you can click on a task instance from your DAG, and  look at Task Instance Details. on that page, I can see a "Task Attributes" section which includes bql and other useful information. I'm trying to figure out a automatic way of pulling such information out.

I found that, although I can get the above info by using the Airflow REST API, but I'd have to pass in specific DAG id and task id for the REST API be able to work, and I'd have to inquiry from somewhere (e.g. Airflow metadata database) to get the list of DAG ids and task ids. I somehow feel it can be cumbersome and ugly to use both metadata database and REST API. Shouldn't be there a smarter way of pulling all BigQueryOperator's task attributes?

My old assumptions are: everything that we can see from its Web UI should be stored in either db or files. So I was hoping to see the BigQueryOperator's task attributes in db too. But it's not in the metadata database.

My questions are:
1) Where are the task attributes of, say BigQueryOperator, stored? 
2) Any smarter way that I can get task attributes of all BigQueryOperator tasks in all active DAGs of under our Airflow project?

The attached screenshot is what I meant with "task attribute"
[image]

[image]

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @ZaxR I think so. you can get task details in DAG runtime , but not in the database

Comment: @foxwendy Is there a way to fetch these values through the `context` (or, more specifically, through the `task_instance`)?